# Sort month and year column in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of date values like below,

> 1) June 2018
>
> 2) March 2017
>
> 3) April 2016
>
> 4) May 2017
>
> 5) September 2016
>
> 6) February 2018

Month is may but year is 2017. It should be sort based on the month and the year.

**How can I sort these date column in AngularJS?**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvqau4z/171/)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appController', appController);

appController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];

function appController($scope, $window) {

  $scope.title = "date sorting example";

  $scope.sortType = "name";
  $scope.sortReverse = true;

  var dateA = new Date("12/10/2017");
  console.log(dateA);
  dateA.setDate(dateA.getDate() + 2);
  var dateB = new Date("08/04/2018");
  dateB.setDate(dateB.getDate() + 4);
  var dateC = new Date("04/09/2016");
  dateC.setDate(dateC.getDate() + 7);
  var dateD = new Date("01/01/2017");
  dateD.setDate(dateD.getDate() + 20);

  $scope.allItems = [{
    date: dateA,
    name: "A"
  }, {
    date: dateB,
    name: "B"
  }, {
    date: dateC,
    name: "C"
  }, {
    date: dateD,
    name: "D"
  }];

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="appController">

    <h1>This is my {{title}}</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
          Date
        </td>
        <td data-ng-click="sortType = name; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
          Name
        </td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in allItems | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
          <td>{{item.date | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>
```

How can I sort these dates based on month and year.

Comment: you can easily do that with `sort()` method in javascript

Comment: @Lokesh can you please send in fiddle. I'm asking in angularjs filter method.